# How to correctly read binary floating-point data using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to read a binary file of floating-point values into an array in JavaScript. Currently I'm doing so by:

```
var mRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
mRequest.open('GET', 'res/binary_float_data.bin');
mRequest.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

mRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (mRequest.readyState === 4) {

        // Get bytes
        var buffer = mRequest.response;
        var dataview = new DataView(buffer);

        // Create buffer (4 bytes / float)
        var mFloatArray = new Float32Array(buffer.byteLength / 4);

        // Copy floats
        for (var i = 0; i < mFloatArray.length; i++) 
        {
            mFloatArray[i] = dataview.getFloat32(i * 4); // At every 4th byte
        }

        console.log("Loaded "+mFloatArray.length+" floats");

        // Do something with mFloatArray
    }
};

mRequest.send();
```

However, when I look at the minimum, maximum, and average values of the resulting array (mFloatArray), they are not correct. They *should* be:

```
min: -0.0094
max: 0.0081
avg: 1.3196e-04
```

Instead I am getting:

```
min: -3.3985008792505584e+38
max: 0
avg: NaN
```

I am certain the binary file is correct, am I correctly parsing the XMLHttpRequest?

**EDIT:** Adding a small part of the binary file, in hex view:

```
0002980: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0002990: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55df 11bc  ............U...
00029a0: afc5 13bc c0b2 15bc 4205 17bc a094 17bc  ........B.......
00029b0: e3d4 17bc cb41 18bc f2e6 18bc 464d 19bc  .....A......FM..
00029c0: bb94 18bc f6ca 16bc 29a5 14bc 0000 0000  ........).......
00029d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

**EDIT 2:**
I made the binary file using matlab and the "fwrite" command, with precision 'float32'. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html

Comment: If you `console.log(mFloatArray)` do you get the values you want?  Out of curiosity, what does `binary_float_data.bin` look like?

Comment: The values in console.log(mFloatArray) are not right, in fact they're all of huge magnitude, both positive and negative. Also, there are no NaN's in the data. binary_float_data.bin in this case is velocities from a hydro simulation, data should look more like  "0.0065    0.0071    0.0002    0.0002    0.0001"

Comment: Is that actually a binary file, or just a text file?  Maybe JavaScript is reading is reading ASCII codes of the characters, instead of "binary" data?

Comment: I added the hex view of the binary file. I made it in matlab using fwrite(vars,'float32') which is a straightforward binary output. Is it possible they are using different floating point formats/representations?

Comment: It seems to me that it has to do with endianness. Also, those zeros at the start of the file are suspicious, if I recall correctly, no floating point number translates into zeroed bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endianness of your data is important: [Javascript Typed Arrays and Endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869752/javascript-typed-arrays-and-endianness)

You'd need to detect endianness and extract the number byte per byte, or create two different versions of the file, detect endianness and retrieve the correct one for the current browser.

Comment: I answered above, but both the default for Matlab's fwrite function and the default for getFloat32 are little endian, and I added the optional arguments to ensure it as well. As far as the matlab documents go, each element is a 32-bit floating point number in little endian. Still no luck...

Comment: Oops! today is opposite day. The default for getFloat32 is Big endian, I changed it by using getFloat32(... , true) and the data looks better, but still not right...

Comment: Accepted because that was definitely an issue, but the data still isn't exactly correct

Comment: Can you post these new numbers? Try generating a file with numbers with a well defined pattern and compare those.

Comment: The last problem was a dumb error in processing the values, once that was fixed, everything looks good! Thanks for your help!