# Creating a typed array from a byte array stored as a node Buffer

Tags: node.js

From the node [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_slice_start_end) regarding the creation of typed arrays from Buffers:

> The buffer's memory is interpreted as an array, not a byte array. That
>   is, `new Uint32Array(new Buffer([1,2,3,4]))` creates a 4-element
>   `Uint32Array` with elements `[1,2,3,4]`, not an `Uint32Array` with a single
>   element `[0x1020304]` or `[0x4030201]`.

This contrasts to plain javascript, where creating a typed array view from an ArrayBuffer uses the ArrayBuffer's memory as bytes (like a `reinterpret_cast` in C++). I need this behavior in node when operating on node Buffers.

I could convert the Buffer to an ArrayBuffer, but this is too slow for my application. (I've tried many methods -- but they're all O(n) time.) (Edit: the fastest method I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394257/1218408), which is a single memmove op and pretty fast, but still has at least momentary 2x memory consumption until the reference to the original Buffer is released.)

**Is there any (fast/O(1)) way to get a typed array from a Buffer, using the Buffer's contents as bytes instead of elements?** (The needed typed array element size is >1 byte, needless to say.)

Comment: What type of operation is supposed to do with the array? If the read-only, then why not refer to elements in the buffer directly through the offset? Ex.: `buf.readUInt32LE(i*4)` where `i` is array index?

Comment: I need to iterate through the array quickly and repeatedly. The `read*` methods are really slow.

Comment: I think that there is no place more quickly: If we need a Int32 value of the index `i`: `var k = i*4; return buf[k] | buf[k+1]<<8 | buf[k+2]<<16 | buf[k+3]<<256;`

Comment: I invented a bicycle: if we look at the module `buffer.js` - is exactly how implemented reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to do this without making a copy of the data in memory.
Even your example `new Uint32Array(new Buffer([1,2,3,4]))` internally does this (meaning it's not O(1)).

Note that typed arrays are just *views* of an `ArrayBuffer` (not `Buffer`, that's not possible). `new Uint32Array(array)` creates an `ArrayBuffer` of `4 * array.length` bytes. You can access it with `uint32Array.buffer`. The constructor treats your `Buffer` no different than a normal `Array`.

The best solution I know is [the one you already found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394257/1218408).

Another issue with using `Uint32Array` for what you try to do is that it [depends on platform byte order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7870190/5127629). You could either iterate over the `Buffer` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31242762/5127629) or use `DataView` if you want to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

As of node 4.0, Buffers are Uint8Arrays and new views can be constructed on them directly:

```
var b = new Buffer([1,2,3,4]);
new Uint32Array(b.buffer, b.byteOffset);
```

This mini-example assumes that `b` is larger than ~4096 (the threshold for a Buffer owning its own chunk of memory vs. sharing a larger chunk). See [Convert a binary NodeJS Buffer to JavaScript ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer/31394257#31394257) for more info -- generally you should call `b.slice()` to operate on only the memory you own.

Comment: NB: `new Uint32Array(b.buffer, b.byteOffset).length` -> `2046` ... doesnt work. You are right -- can be constructed directly, but "as uint8array" is not bytes.

Comment: @shaunc it does work, look at the contents of the result. The unexpected length is a side-effect of node's shared array buffer allocator. Use `b.slice` at least when your buffer is small, or always to be safe.

Comment: `new Uint32Array(b.buffer, b.byteOffset).slice(0,4)` -> `Uint32Array [ 67305985, 0, 8192, 0 ]` ? the same when I rewrite both "b"s as `b.slice(0,4)`? (NB: node 9.3.0) OOPS ... I guess thats right :) Grumble ... won't let me correct my mistake by upvote until you edit -- any edit will do and I'll upvote. Sorry

Comment: No prob, clarified. Cheers.