# Node.js buffer to typed array

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js I have a Buffer (It was stored as a blob in mysql and retrieved using sequelize)
I know that this Buffer is an array of 16 bit integers.  In the past I've parsed the code with a for loop.

```
    var spectrum_buffer = spectrums[idx]["spectrum"];//this is a buffer
    var parsed_spectrum = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < spectrum_buffer.length / 2; i++) {
        parsed_spectrum[i] = spectrum_buffer.readInt16BE(i * 2);
    }
```

I've read that readInt16BE is slow and that there are typedarrays for arraybuffers now. (which are different than Buffers). Is there a better way of creating an array of ints from this buffer.

Update 1

Based on the feedback I did the following

```
var arr = new Int16Array(spectrum.buffer)
```

Which gives me the appropriate type however the bytes are getting swapped.  The spectrum buffer is stored in big endian.

> < Buffer e1 d7 e0 b9 e3 52 e2 d5 e2 ed e2 92 e2 d6 e2 97 e3 04 e1 95 e1 e2 > e1 d8 e3 14 e2 fd e1 ed e2 d3 e3 09 e1 9f e2 14 e2 f2 e2 54 e2 1f e2 54 > e2 06 e2 8a ... >

The first three numbers are coming across as -10271, -17952, 21219

However they should not vary that much and all three should be negative.

The first number should be -7721 (twos complement always confuses me)

So does Int16Array on node 6 assume  big endian or little endian and how do I handle this.

Comment: Note: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray Sure looks like it's possible, if you create the typed array *before* filling the buffer.

Comment: Just so you know, I updated my answer. There's an even lower level interface you can use if you need to read the data with a certain endianess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Node.js buffers [are a special instance](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray) of [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array).

So if you wanted to create an instance of a [`Int16Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int16Array) you could create a copy of your buffer:

```
var int16Arr = new Int16Array(spectrum_buffer);
```

or create a new array which references the same underlying buffer, which means you don't have to copy all of the data:

```
var int16Arr = new Int16Array(spectrum_buffer.buffer);
```

Update:

Typed arrays default to using the native byte order. If you need to specify the byte order, you can use a lower-level interface: [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView).

A `DataView` is a wrapper around a Buffer which gives you full control over how that data is accessed. In your case, you would want to use the [`getInt16`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getInt16) method and set the endianess flag as needed for your data:

```
var littleEndian = true; // or false, depends on your needs
var dataView = new DataView(spectrum.buffer);
dataView.getInt16(offset, littleEndian);
```

Comment: Both `new Int16Array` calls above will create 1 value per byte, not recreate the typed array from the byte data.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica If you want to recreate a typed array from the byte data, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30604777/2441655) and [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31483629/2441655) for background, then read the ["best solution" link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394257/2441655) for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//this is a buffer
var spectrum_buffer = spectrums[idx]["spectrum"];

// these two views share same memory
var int16view = new Int16Array(spectrum_buffer); 
var uint8view = new Uint8Array(spectrum_buffer);

var parsed_spectrum = [];

for (var i = 0; i < int16view.length; i++) {
    // swap byte order
    [uint8view[i*2], uint8view[i*2+1]] = [uint8view[i*2+1], uint8view[i*2]]; // ES6 swap
    // read swapped bytes as Int16
    parsed_spectrum[i] = int16view[i];
}
```