# Why is Javascript TypeDArray not working?

Tags: javascript, dataview, typedarray

I have 4 bytes ArrayBuffer and I assigned a number at the index 0 using dataview. When I try to get the value using dataview that gives result correctly but it does not give correct result when I try to get value using typed array. Can anyone help on this? Here are the code:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var dataview = new DataView(buffer);
dataview.setUint32(0,5000);

var unint32 = new Uint32Array(buffer);

console.log(unint32[0]); //2282946560 instead of 5000
console.log(dataview.getUint32(0)); //shows correctly 5000
```

Comment: Closely related to (or duplicate of?) [Javascript Typed Arrays and Endianness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869752/javascript-typed-arrays-and-endianness)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're using the wrong endian-type when using [`setUint32`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setUint32). Specifically, you need it to store a little-endian representation, because your hardware behaves like that.

You can see this more easily using hexadecimal values. Now, `5000 === 0x1388`, while `2282946560 = 0x88130000`. Can you see the pattern here?

Try this instead:

```
dataview.setUint32(0, 5000, true);

var unint32 = new Uint32Array(buffer);

console.log(unint32[0]); // 5000, yay!
```

As apsillers pointed out, if you're going to use `dataview` to retrieve the value too, you'll also have to use `dataview.getUint32(0, true)`.

As a last word, if you just need to work with `Uint32` numbers, forget about the `DataView` and use the typed array right away:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
var unint32 = new Uint32Array(buffer);
unint32[0] = 5000;
```

You'll never get it wrong with this.

On the other hand, if you need to fill an `ArrayBuffer` with raw binary data, you'd like to check then endiannes of your hardware with [this little trick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView#Endianness).

Comment: @apsillers you are correct. I think in that case I have to use dataview.getUint32(0,true)