# Most efficent way to convert a non-typed array of 32-bit integers to a UInt8Array?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I need to take a standard javascript array populated with valid 32-bit signed intergers and convert it to a `UInt8Array`.  For example, consider the following standard javascript array:

```
[255, 3498766, -99]
```

I want the resulting `UInt8Array` to contain the signed 32-bit representation of these numbers:

```
255     = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF]
3498766 = [0x00, 0x35, 0x63, 0x0E]
-99     = [0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x9D]
```

So, given the an input of `[255, 3498766, -99]`, the result would be:

```
[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x35, 0x63, 0x0E, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x9D]
```

I can think of naive ways to accomplish this, but I'm looking for as direct a conversion as possible.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
a = [255, 3498766, -99]
b = new Uint8Array(Int32Array.from(a).buffer)
console.log(b)
```

The result will be in the platform byte order, i.e. LE on most today's processors. If you really want big-endian as in your example, you'll need some additional fiddling with `DataView.getInt32` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869752/javascript-typed-arrays-and-endianness) for details).

Comment: LE is fine.  Example was BE only because that's how I visualize it.