# What determines bit endianness in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, endianness, bitmask

In Javascript, byte endianness is determined by the underlying hardware. Through `DataView`, you can assign byte endianness as big or little.

What is the behavior for bit endianness? Will it inherit from hardware as well? Can `DataView` manipulate bit endianness as well?

I have a bitmask in a UI which may run on machines which are big or little endian.

Will `Number(n).toString(2)` return the same order regardless of machine hardware or `DataView` assignment? 
Will `Number(2).toString(2)` always return `"10"`?

Comment: Bit endianness does not exist. Bits don't have address.

Comment: @slebetman - [I have come across a few examples which describe the order of the bits in similar terms.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bit_endianness)

Comment: That has nothing to do with memory thus it has nothing to do with javascript. Bit endianness only applies when you have to transmit digital data over a wire or radio signal because both a single wire and radios can only transmit one bit at a time - thus you are forced to decide which bit to send first

Comment: A question asking "what is the bit endianness on Wifi" or "what is the bit endianness in USB" makes sense. A question asking "what is the bit endianness in javascript" or "what is the bit endianness on intel CPU" makes no sense

Comment: "one bit at a time" - I'm of course overly simplifying here but the point still stands

Comment: @slebetman Ok, based on this [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869752/javascript-typed-arrays-and-endianness) I had the impression that this _is_ something that should be considered as hardware can influence it. I'm just trying to verify that `Number(2).toString(2)` always return `"10"` regardless of hardware.

Comment: Yes. That's always the case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869752/javascript-typed-arrays-and-endianness

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment by @slebetman, `Number(2).toString(2)` will always return `"10"`.